# reflection Problem: passing arguments array with int[] inside it

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a problem with this:

```
objectType.GetMethod("setValues").Invoke(testClass, arguments);
```

arguments is an array of objects, can any member of it be an array of any type like this int[]???
I'm asking this because I have an exception when passing arguments with an int[] array as a member in it, this is the exception:

System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32[]'.

Any suggestions??

Comment: My advice: write a small program that we can actually compile and run that demonstrates the problem. Then post that program. Otherwise it's just guessing; we don't know what is in arguments, objectType, testclass, or what the signature of setValues is, so we cannot diagnose the problem except psychically.

Comment: ... and as it's probably *not* an iterator block problem, psychic debugging is at a disadvantage ;) (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/05/psychic-debugging-part-one.aspx, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/06/psychic-debugging-part-two.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to pass an array of integers as one of the parameters to a reflection call.  From the error it looks like what you think is an array of integers is actually an array of objects though.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging suggests that the signature of `setValues` looks like this:

```
public void setValues(int[] vals);
```

And you're passing an `int[]` to `Invoke`, like so:

```
int[] arguments = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
objectType.GetMethod("setValues").Invoke(testClass, arguments);
```

This doesn't work, because the `object[]` that you pass to `Invoke` is flattened to create the actual argument list. In other words, your invocation is equivalent to calling `setValues(1, 2, 3)`, which doesn't work because `setValues` wants a single `int[]` parameter, not a series of `int` parameters. You need to do the following:

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
object[] arguments = new object[] { values };
objectType.GetMethod("setValues").Invoke(testClass, arguments);
```